# How do I display a photo?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to write a project with JavaFX How can I display a picture ???
For example, I want to show the welcome picture first.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of the class ImageView. https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html You will find a complete working example in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this its fairly straightforward just make sure that the path to your image is correct.  If you really wanted to have some fun you could create a timer that auto-closes the stage as well

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private void showStartupWelcomeImage(){
        Image image = new Image("pathToYourHelloImage.png");

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(imageView);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Welcome");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        showStartupWelcomeImage();
        //Run actual code below
    }
}
```